# Adding table to an 'already-created database'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to build a database with multiple tables in MVC.
I built a model.cs with the table attributes and let Entity Framework do its thing.
Now I want to create a new table in the same database and link them.

I have tried "creating new table" in the database where my previous table exists. This hands out a type-mismatch exception, invalid key exception, etc...

I also tried adding a new class within the model and tying it to the context...that doesn't help either...

code looks SOMETHING like this....

---

```
namespace bleh.bleh
{
    public partial class T1
    {
        //.....attributes primary key
    }

    public class T2
    {
        //...attributes foreign key to T1
    }

    public class TEntity : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<T1> Tab1....
        public DbSet<T2> Tab2....
    }
}
```

Please advise...

Comment: I don't think EF has any way to update a database to match changes to your model.  You'll probably need to delete the database and re-create it, making sure to back up any data you want to keep.

Comment: @john: thx bro!!

I was considering integrating NHibernate to reconfigure my db and...u think dat would be any good?

Comment: Is this EF 4.3? If so, you could take a look at [Code-Based Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found: add the following line in the StartApplication method of the global.asax file:

```
Database.SetInitializer<FTContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<FTContext>());
```